# How to optimize image after crop using php?

Tags: php, jquery, image, optimization, image-resizing

I am using https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/ plugin for the cropping image. Everything is working perfectly. I am able to crop the image and after crop the image able to insert the image in my folder and database.

The issue is sometimes I am getting image size 300kb and same time I am getting the image more than 5MB or 10 MB. I want to reduce the size of the image after cropping. I need in KB

```
$data = $_POST['imagebase64'];
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
$imageName = time().'.png';
$destination_img= "images/profile/";
/*image optimizer code here*/

//help me with code

/*end optimizer code*/
file_put_contents('images/profile/'.$imageName, $data);
```

Comment: the best idea is to store an image into the temp folder. then optimize it and post into its directory.

Comment: How can we optimize image after stored in the folder?

Comment: you know the path where you are storing it. get that image and then compress it. simple.

Comment: or read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255521/compress-save-base64-image

Comment: What I did I remove the compress function and added resizeAndCompressImagefunction which is in above link but nothing is happing.

Answer (score 0):

for quality you need to pass height and width as well. So if you want to keep the original height and width then you can use $data['width'] $data['height'], please check in your library if you have it or not.

Comment: but where should I pass it? Can you help me with the code? So that I can understand

Comment: Your code is uncomplete, there is something wrong, i need more data

Comment: Above code is only cropping image will store in the folder which is working. I need code for reducing the size of image